# Getting error while displaying the message using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error while trying to display the message after form submit only using React.js.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined
TodoList.addItem
src/TodoList.js:30
  27 |       items:itemArray
  28 |     })
  29 |     this.inputElement.value='';
> 30 |     this.form.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", '<p>Added successfully</p>');
```

Here is my code:

```
addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.editKey){
      this.saveEditedText();
      return;
    }
    var itemArray = this.state.items;
    if (this.inputElement.value !== '') {
      itemArray.unshift({
        text:this.inputElement.value,
        key:Date.now()
      })
      this.setState({
        items:itemArray
      })
      this.inputElement.value='';
      this.form.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", '<p>Added successfully</p>');
    }
  }
<div className="wrapper">
<form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
<input ref={(a)=>this.inputElement=a} placeholder="enter task">
 </input>
<button type="submit">{this.state.editKey? "Update": "Add"}</button>
</form>
<TodoItems entries={this.state.items} delete={this.deleteItem} edit={this.editItem}/>
</div>
```

Here I need to display the success message means after form submit this message will exact before the form element.

Comment: Where is this.form ? You didn't set ref for from.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here `form onSubmit={this.addItem}>` you haven't assigned ref to the form

change it to `<form ref={(el)=>this.form=el)} onSubmit={this.addItem}>`

Comment: I did like `<div ref={divEl => {
            this.divRef = divEl;
          }}></div> and this.divRef.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<p className="textcolor">Added successfully</p>');` but How can it be removed after 1/2 sec of showing.